# Yii CGridView или свой Widget на bootstrap?

Tags: cgridview, bootstrap, yii

Есть много модулей с таблицами, вопрос: использовать CGridView(но уж очень он мне не нравится) или же лучше написать своё (и изобрести велосипед)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласен полностью с [@Barton](/users/1971/barton) и отчасти с [@Ale_x](/users/3785/ale_x).

Но, есть своё но.

Использую именно **CGridView**, функциональность его огромная. Как раз недавно использовал интересные вещи с его использованием. У него есть куча опций. Изменить поле, добавить поле, сделать свою выборку и прочее, css и многое другое, зачем изобретать велосипед в готовом фреймворке? Не, однозначно не стоит!

Comment: Ок. Решил просто наследовать от CGridView и переточить нужное под себя. Ночью буду экспериментировать...
Может подскажете хорошие рецепты с CGridView?

Comment: [Ссылка на форум][1]
плюс [api][1]



  [1]: http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2317
  [2]http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

Answer (score 1):

Что именно не нравится в CGridView? 
Если оформление, так к нему можно подключить свой css и оформить так, как вам надо. В остальном он достаточно функциональный

Answer (score 0):

Смотря как быстро надо Вам сделать проект) Но я бы поступил следующим образом - на начальном этапе разработке пользовался бы встроенными виджетами, так сказать показывл бы заказчику  результаты именно работы логики приложения. А вот когда логика будет отточена можно взяться и за интерфейс приложения.